# upgrade qt 5.6 to 5.9 in centos 7

Tags: centos, qt, qtcreator

CentOS 7 ships with Qt 5.6, is there a way of upgrading to Qt 5.9?.

current version.

```
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.6.2 in /usr/lib64
```

I dont want to install Qt from [qt.io](https://www1.qt.io/download-open-source/?hsCtaTracking=f977210e-de67-475f-a32b-65cec207fd03%7Cd62710cd-e1db-46aa-8d4d-2f1c1ffdacea#section-2), as I am not going to develop applications, the application I'm trying to run requires `QtQuick version 2.9` which is available in Qt 5.9.

Answer (score 0):

Piecemeal installation of versions of parts of packages usually leads to bad things.

If you can, runs your app inside a container using docker or similar. Otherwise you might get away with downloading a Fedora package and installing it in a local path or in /usr/local.

Packages here? https://rpms.remirepo.net/rpmphp/zoom.php?rpm=qt5-qtbase